# iOS App with IBM MobileFirst server , issue {"error_description":"Client authentication failed","error":"invalid_client"}

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

In Production, IBM MobileFirst server running with version 7.1.0.00.20180425-1124 and Project war file with version 7.1.0.00.20180425-1124.

Recent deployment of project war was deployed with 7.1.0.00.20161006-0540, unfortunately.

**iOS throws below error:**

```
{"error_description":"Client authentication failed","error":"invalid_client"}
```

Rolled back the deployment to avoid issues.

While investigating, there was an [APAR](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI64135) with similar fix but the version used in the deployment doesn't include this APAR.

> Question 1: If same version(7.1.0.00.20180425-1124) of MF Plugin used to build Project .war, will this issue be addressed.
>
> Question 2: Where can I download the Eclipse Plugin of 7.1.0.00.20180425-1124?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved by clearing out the keychain items and defaults which work light library has been internally maintaining.

So what's happening behind the scenes is the work light client is creating and maintaining some keychain items and also few user defaults. This is done for storing some information like session id's and stuff. Sometimes the data in the keychain or defaults is getting corrupted during the initial work light handshake with MFP server. In this scenario we get the above error. Once we clear them out and kill the app and launch again. the app will now behave as a new device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what steps you took to update your server. In your MobileFirst server Operations console , if you see the version as "7.1.0.00.20161006-0540" , then you should definitely update.

If that is the case, merely building a new project runtime war file in latest MobileFirst Eclipse Studio and deploying it will not help. The iFix level in the server will have to be updated too. You can use Server Config Tool or ANT scripts to update your iFix level as well to the latest while you deploy the new runtime war.

You can download the latest versions of the iFix ( Server and Studio plugin) in [FixCentral](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%20software&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=7.1.0.0&platform=All&function=all).